# how to add close [X] icon to djextNameTextBox?

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, xpages, dijit.form

Not sure why but on some page this control has [X] icon and on another ones doesn't. I need to be able to remove name from the list by click on this icon

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view 
       xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
       xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
       xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

<xe:djextNameTextBox id="djextNameTextBox1" multipleSeparator="," multipleTrim="true">
    <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"NAME1,NAME2,NAME3"}]]>/xe:this.value>
</xe:djextNameTextBox>
</xp:view>
```

Playing with .lotusFilter .lotusClose css doesn't help. This icon just appear in design mode but I don't see it on my xPage
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The X icon is used to remove the selected option(s) from whatever the field is bound to. It's not added via CSS, it's only added if the component can be edited, but in your implementation it's not.

The `value` property, for this and for any editable component, is used to bind it to a scoped variable or datasource property (e.g. `#{document1.myField}`). It defines where you want to store the data, not default values (that's `defaultValue` property). So `<xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"NAME1,NAME2,NAME3"}]]>/xe:this.value>` means you're trying to store whatever is selected into a String called "NAME1,NAME2,NAME3". Because that's not editable and cannot be stored anywhere, it's not allowing you to remove the values - it's effectively displaying a readonly version of the component.

You need to use the `value` property to map to a datasource property. If you want a default values, that can be done either in `defaultValue` property or `beforePageLoad` or other such event. (I'm not sure if a single comma-separated string will work to set a default value or if you'll need to pass a array / Vector / List.)

I would strongly suggest looking at the examples in the Extension Library Demo database (XPagesExt.nsf in the OpenNTF download files), specifically Domino_Pickers.xsp, Name Pickers tab. It's the best reference for any of the Extension Library components and was the key resource we used when writing XPages Extension Library book.